# Capturar datos de un formulario html5 con javascript y guardarlos en un objeto

Tags: javascript, html5, formularios

Cuando pulse clic sobre el botón “Enviar datos”, se debe crear un objeto con los datos capturados. Cuando pulse “Cancelar” el objeto tendrá todos los atributos en null, no he podido lograr capturar los datos del formulario, no se si deba mejor hacer un boton o con los input submit se puede, simplemente debo capturarlos y guardarlos en un objeto.
muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```js
((doc, win) => {
    doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {

        console.log('Cargado el contenido del DOM');  

        function crearListaDesplegable(idlista, arrayObj){
            let select = document.getElementById(idlista);
            for (let index in arrayObj){
                select.options[select.options.length] 
                = new Option(arrayObj[index]['nombre'], arrayObj[index]['codigo']);
            }
        }
        crearListaDesplegable('deptos', Departamento.getDepartamentos());

        let selectdeptos = doc.getElementById('deptos');
        crearListaDesplegable('ciudades',Ciudad.depto('05'));

        selectdeptos.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

            let select2 = document.getElementById('ciudades');
            let val = selectdeptos.value;
            select2.innerHTML="";         
            crearListaDesplegable('ciudades',Ciudad.depto(val));

        }, false);

            
    });

})(document, window);
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
     <h1>Registro</h1>
        <form name="formulario">
            <label>Nombres</label>
           <input type="text" id="nombre" class="inp" name="nombres">
           <br>
         <label>Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" class="inp" name="apellidos"> <br>                      
          <label>Dirección fisica</label>
         <input type="text"  id="direccion" class="inp" name="direccion">
              <br>
        <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="correo" class="inp" name="email">
             <br>
        <label>Departamento</label>
       <select id="deptos"></select>
       <br>
       <label>Ciudad</label>
     <select id="ciudades"></select>
     <br>
      <div class="btn_form">
      <input class="btn_submit" id="btn1" type="submit" name="limpiar" value="Limpiar">
      <input class="btn_submit" id="btn2" type="submit" name="registrarse" value="Registrarse">
         </div>
         </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Cambia el tipo de botón de `type="submit"` al tipo `type="button"` y comenta los resultados. También podrías cambiar el elemento, en vez de usar un `<input>` para los botones de acción, puedes usar un elemento `<button>`. Saludos

Comment: Mejor sería hacerlo manual, pero sino puedes hacer algo como `[...new FormData(document.getElementsByName("formulario")[0])]` para tener un objeto con todo el formulario en una línea.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sirvio cambiar al tipo type="button" ya que se me refrescaba la pagina y no podía guardar los datos pero ya logre guardarlos